Proving a differentiable relation.
Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and $z=\frac{y^2}{2}+\varphi(\frac{1}{x} + \log y).$ Show that
$$y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} + x^2 \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= y^2.$$
I tried doing this
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\bigg( \frac{y^2}{2} + \varphi \bigg(\frac {1}{x} + \log y \bigg) \bigg)= 0 + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \bigg( \frac{1}{x} + \log y \bigg) \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} \bigg(\frac{1}{x} +\log y \bigg) =$$
$$=- \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} \bigg(\frac{1}{x} +\log y \bigg).$$
And furthermore,
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg( \frac{y^2}{2} + \varphi \bigg(\frac {1}{x} + \log y \bigg) \bigg)= y + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \bigg( \frac{1}{x} + \log y \bigg) \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y} \bigg(\frac{1}{x} +\log y \bigg) =$$
$$=y + \frac{1}{y} \cdot \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y} \bigg(\frac{1}{x} +\log y \bigg).$$
Thus,
$$y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} + x^2 \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= 
y \cdot \bigg [y + \frac{1}{y} \cdot \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y} \bigg(\frac{1}{x} +\log y \bigg) \bigg ] + x^2 \cdot \bigg [- \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} \bigg(\frac{1}{x} +\log y \bigg) \bigg ]=$$
$$=y^2 + \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y} \bigg(\frac{1}{x} +\log y \bigg) - \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} \bigg(\frac{1}{x} +\log y \bigg)$$
I'm not sure on what to do next. I thought that if $\varphi$ is a single variable function then the derivatives with the respect to $x$ and $y$ are the same, however, I'm not sure if this is true.

Start by computing the derivatives.

Thank you, Anne !!

So when I do the partial derivatives, I should do the total derivative of $\varphi$ ?

Thank you, Anne!

Please post the resolution to your question as an answer instead of as an edit to the question itself (and accept it, ideally) so this question doesn't go unanswered :)

$φ:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$
is a single variable function. Replace all your $\frac{∂φ}{∂x}$
and  $\frac{∂φ}{∂y}$
by simply $φ′$, and you are (well) done:
$$y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} + x^2 \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=y^2 + \varphi \prime \bigg (\frac{1}{x} + \log y \bigg ) - \varphi \prime \bigg (\frac{1}{x} + \log y \bigg ) = y^2.$$

Thanks, Anne!!!

Using differentials yields
$$
dz = 
y dy + 
\varphi'
\left(\frac{1}{x} + \log y \right)
\left[ \frac{1}{y} dy -
\frac{1}{x^2} dx \right]
$$
thus regrouping terms
\begin{eqnarray}
y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} + 
x^2 \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} 
&=&
y(y+\frac{\varphi'}{y}) -
x^2 \frac{\varphi'}{x^2} = 
y^2
\end{eqnarray}
